# How to fix FTP to self?

Tags: ftp

I am able to `ftp` into my server, but when log on via ssh and do `ftp localhost`, I receive the message `ftp> ftp: connect: Connection refused`. I think I need it to ftp to itself for wordpress. Is this a firewall issue? How can I diagnose it?

Comment: What is the "it" in "it cannot ftp to itself"? I don't understand the problem?

Comment: I believe you will get more help going to stackoverflow or superuser. It is not a special question for askubuntu.

Comment: @HongboZhu ah, I didn't know if my problem was system specific, related to the firewall Ubuntu uses, or something to do with the specific distro I'm using

Comment: After searching the documents for several hours, I've come to the conclusion that Ubuntu is not supposed to ship with an FTP and so I have no idea what `fpt`  program I'm using. I just followed the same tutorial in byaruhaf's comment, and that made it run, so as long as it's working, I don't want to spend any more time at work on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should can try sftp, but if you need ftp then you need to setup and ftp server

- vsftpd is an FTP daemon available in Ubuntu. It is easy to install,
  set up, and maintain. To install vsftpd you can run the following
  command:

sudo apt-get install vsftpd

[Click here for more details on FTP Server setup](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/ftp-server.html)

Comment: If I'm able to already `ftp` in to my server, does that mean I've already set it up correctly, or do I need to change something?

Comment: if you can already ftp in to the server it means its setup correctly. have you tried sftp.

Comment: `sftp` does work, I'm able to start a connection that way. Why can I do one and not the other?

Comment: Outside their similar names and interactive user interfaces, there is no relationship between ftp and sftp. sftp is actually ssh based rather than ftp, for example, WinSCP uses SFTP as it's default transfer method. This means if you can SSH to a node, you can SFTP files to/from it. I'm also not a ftp expert, but I believe You need to configure the FTP server. Most admins disable ftp because ftp transmits your password in the clear.